# Cloud Functions for Firebase HTTP timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm so close with this one.

I have written a Cloud Function that takes information sent from an **Azure** token to custom mint a Firebase token and send this token back to the client.

The token is created correctly, but isn't returned on my HTTP-request.

Unfortunately my Firebase app causes a timeout.

> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

I can't really wrap my head around why that is, hence this post. Is there something wrong with my code, or is it me that's calling the HTTP-request wrong?

Here is the log I get from the Firebase Functions console.

[image: Firebase functions log]

Here's my code

```
// Create a Firebase token from any UID
exports.createFirebaseToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  // The UID and other things we'll assign to the user.
  const uid = req.body.uid;
  const additionalClaims = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email
  };

  // Create or update the user account.
  const userCreationTask = admin.auth().updateUser(uid, additionalClaims).catch(error => {

    // If user does not exists we create it.
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      console.log(`Created user with UID:${uid}, Name: ${additionalClaims.name} and e-mail: ${additionalClaims.email}`);
      return admin.auth().createUser({
        uid: uid,
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
      });
    }
    throw error;
    console.log('Error!');
  });

  // Wait for all async tasks to complete, then generate and return a custom auth token.
  return Promise.all([userCreationTask]).then(() => {
    console.log('Function create token triggered');
    // Create a Firebase custom auth token.
    return admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims).then((token) => {
      console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
      return token;
    });
  });
});
```

When I'm making this HTTP-request, all i'm sending in is a `JSON` that looks like this:

```
parameters = [
    "uid" : id,
    "email" : mail,
    "name" : name
]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cloud Functions triggered by HTTP requests need to be terminated by ending them with a `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`, otherwise they will continue running and reach the timeout.

From the [terminate HTTP functions section of the documentation on HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions):

> Always end an HTTP function with `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`. Otherwise, your function might to continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system. See also [Sync, Async and Promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).
>
> After retrieving and formatting the server time using the Node.js [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) module, the `date()` function concludes by sending the result in the HTTP response:
>
> ```
> const formattedDate = moment().format(format);
> console.log('Sending Formatted date:', formattedDate);
> res.status(200).send(formattedDate);
> ```

So, within your code, you could send the token back in the response with `send()`, for example:

```
// ...
// Create a Firebase custom auth token.
return admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims).then((token) => {
  console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
  res.status(200).send(token);
  return token;
});
// ...
```