# Firebase last 10 data retrieving from database in Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

The below Cloud Function only returns the first data instead of 10:

```
exports.viewdata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.user;
    return admin.database().ref('users/' + userId)
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(10)    
    .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        res.status(200).send(data.val());
        });
     });
});
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `send()`, `end()` or `redirect()` will [terminate a HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions):

> Always end an HTTP function with `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`. Otherwise, your function might to continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system.

In your example, you are calling `res.status(200).send(data.val());` inside your `forEach` iteration of each child snapshot, therefore it will only get a chance to send the one response.

Likewise, because you have used a [`child_added` event listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added), it is triggered once for every child at the specified path.

If you need to respond with all the query data at once, you'll be better off with a [`value` event listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value) instead, which will retrieve all data from your query in a single response:

```
exports.viewdata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.user;
    admin.database().ref('users/' + userId)
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(10)    
    .on('value', function(snapshot) {
        res.status(200).send(snapshot.val());
    });
});
```

However, if your intention is to build a response with each child separately, you could use `res.write()` to write data to the response, and then eventually send this with `end()`:

```
exports.viewdata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.user;
    admin.database().ref('users/' + userId)
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(10)    
    .on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            res.write(data.val());
        });
        res.status(200).end();
    });
});
```

Or, you could add them to a list before sending them all back as a response. The method you take here all depends on your end-goal though.

---

Unrelated to your initial question, but for completeness, please see the below observations and side notes, from comments:

- The `return` statement for `admin.database().ref()` is not required for HTTPS triggers as they have a [different lifecycle than other triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and do not need to return promises.
- If you have no need to listen for further changes after you've retrieved the necessary data, you should consider using [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) (to [read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)) instead of `on()` or removing the `on()` listener with [`off()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off).

Comment: Almost. A few more things are needed to make this work: 1) listen for the `value` event, so that the callback gets all 10 children at once. 2) either build the result using a `forEach` **or** send the 10 results in one go with `snapshot.val()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ah yeah, I missed the `child_added` part! Thanks Frank, I'll update the answer.

Comment: There's no need for the `return` here, since the return value from an HTTPS function doesn't mean anything (also, on() doesn't even return a promise or anything useful like that).

Comment: Also consider removing the listener with `off()` so that it doesn't continue to listen after the function returns - that could be wasteful.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks you're right, I [answered another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47328078/2754146) earlier today where dropping the `return` is necessary. Also, using `once()` would be better here to avoid leaving the listener attached.